# Unexpected value of a shared pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have recently started learning shared pointers and need some help.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    int a;
    A (int x) {
      a = x;
    }
    int print() {
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{   
    shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<A>>> vec1 = make_shared<vector<shared_ptr<A>>>(1);
    (*vec1)[0] = make_shared<A>(50);
    shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<A>>> vec2 = make_shared<vector<shared_ptr<A>>>();
    vec2->push_back((*vec1)[0]);
    for (shared_ptr<A>& obj : *vec2) {
        obj = make_shared<A>(100);
    }
    cout << (*((*vec1)[0])).a;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the output as 50 while I expected it to be 100. Can some please explain why? And what can I do to get this as 100? TIA!

Comment: try `for (shared_ptr<A>& obj : *vec2)`

Comment: You are looping by value, so the element with 100 only exists for a brief moment. You want `shared_ptr<A>& obj`

Comment: Thanks! Changed it but still getting the output as 50

Comment: Your new code is changing the value of `vec2` (and no longer sharing that with `vec1`, because `make_shared` replaces it with a different share), but you are printing the value in `vec1`.  You could use `*obj = 100;` to change the *shared* value to 100 for both of them.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Is there any other way to do this with shared pointers instead of using raw pointers?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (shared_ptr<A> obj : *vec2) {
    obj = make_shared<A>(100);
}
```

This makes the shared pointer obj, pointing to the same object A{50}. Then the shared pointer obj is reset to point to new object A{100}, but the original shared pointer vec2[0] keeps pointing to the first object A{50}.

Comment: Thanks! Changed it but still getting the output as 50

Comment: You reset the element of the vec2, why do you output the element of the vec1?